# Middleware to get headers with underscores?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, http-headers

I am making a server for a chinese manufactured hardware device. I cannot change it's firmware. The http requests sent by this device use headers with underscores which are getting stripped by django. I am new to django I need a clear workaround for this.
A friend told me you might need to write a Middleware for it can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It's not stripped by middleware. Its stripped by the [builtin dev server](https://github.com/django/django/blob/7785e03ba89aafbd949191f126361fb9103cb980/django/core/servers/basehttp.py)(./manage runserver) take a look at get_environ. I'm not sure you can do something about the builtin server without modifying the django core code. In Apache and Nginx, they are stripped too, but you can disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, you can run your django server by gunicorn: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/run.html#django

Try:

`curl -X GET -H "custom_header: xxxxxxxxx" "http://gunicorn-django-server/api"`

And you will get the value of 'HTTP_CUSTOM_HEADER' from request.META (or 'Custom-Header' from request.headers [django>=v2.2])

Good luck.